# Can't find my git branch on the git repo

Tags: github

I've forked a repo, and checkout a new branch, modified and rebased it on the upstream/master. I want to create a pull request now, and I couldnt see the new branch I have created. Could it be on a different remote? Is there a way to see this?

Thanks

Comment: did you push it..?

Comment: I did, and I used git checkout -b new_branch to checkout the new branch